# compress or zip iOS sqlite Database

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, compression, zip

People,

How Can I Zip my iOS app's sqlite database? Because I'm trying to sinc it with the cloud but im having some troubles...

Which classes I'm supposed to use to zip it ? please help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ZipArchive, its a objective c wrapper to zip/unzip - 
http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

for zip :-

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* dPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* txtfile = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
    NSString* zipfile = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.zip"];
    ZipArchive* zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    BOOL ret = [zip CreateZipFile2:zipfile];
    ret = [zip addFileToZip:txtfile newname:@"test.txt"];//zip
    if( ![zip CloseZipFile2] )
    {
        zipfile = @"";
    }
    [zip release];
    NSLog(@"The file has been zipped");
```

Comment: specifically, how can I zip the .sqlite archive? how can I access it?

Comment: don't you know the path of your db file ?

Comment: it is on the resources of the app, but i never worked with archives on iOS so Im a lil bit lost...

Comment: How can I explore the files in the simulator? I've already ziped and unziped, but i'm not sure its there...

Answer (score 0):

you can use Zlib which is available at: http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/

Comment: specifically, how can I zip the .sqlite archive? how can I access it?

Comment: no, I just needed the way to find my db archive cuz I never used the ios file system...